# QGIS clip tool doesn't regenerate geometry column in attribute table

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, clip, well-known-binary

I have a lot of large datasets which all contain WKB defined geometry (point and polygon separate), which makes it easy to load in QGIS from a PostGIS-database. This format is also preferable when using Geoserver to display data through WMS later on.

When i clip the set of polygons (with a lot of other polygons) the result is good visually, but the new shapefile does not have a geometry column, it rather generates only a point_geometry, while the polygon_geometry disappears. The result is still shown in polygon-format in QGIS.

When trying to load this shapefile into PostGIS through the PostGIS Shapefile import/export manager (With "Create spatial index automatically after load") I don't get the polygon-geometry recreated, and I am not able to use the table either in QGIS or Geoserver at all as the table has "No geometry"

I've searched for ages trying to find a viable solution to regenerate these WKB-type geometries on the clipped polygons, as this is LARGE datasets and many different clips. Anyone have any idea how i can get this done?